# Ubuntu 16.04 install +Nvidia 367 boot crash not working loop etc

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I got this loop black screen problem with `nvidia` driver after fresh install.
the only solution that worked for me after be stuck in a loop is to reinstall Ubuntu `+Nvidia` driver as follow:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Install the nvidia driver (don't restart)
3. Open Terminal : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-367`
4. Restart.

Answer (score 1):

1/ You do not state which Nvidia card you have. Not all drivers work with all cards. A mismatch can give many problems.

2/ You are best advised to perform another fresh install from a DVD, and allow Ubuntu to detect and install the generic driver for your card.

3/ Determine your exact card and use Synaptic to find and install the correct drivers. Then use Synaptic menu "settings/repositories/additional drivers" to choose the correct driver.